# Appending to a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I am having the weirdest problem, perhaps someone could explain this to me. I am trying to do some tuple manipulation:

```
rec_tuple = ()
sender = 'a'
message = 'b'
subject = 'c'
for i in range(1,4):
    message = (subject, message, sender)
    rec_tuple = rec_tuple+message
```

output for rec_tuple:

```
('c', 'b', 'a', 'c', ('c', 'b', 'a'), 'a', 'c', ('c', ('c', 'b', 'a'), 'a'), 'a')
```

The tuple concatenation doesn't seem to be working properly. But when I do:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    message = ('a', 'b', 'c')
    rec_tuple = rec_tuple+message
```

output for rec_tuple:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

Which agrees with the docs. So why can't I pass in variables to create my tuple? Is there another way that I should be doing this?

Comment: Don't override your variables

Comment: Terminology alert: You don't append to tuples, since they are immutable.  You concatenate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
message = (subject, message, sender)
rec_tuple = rec_tuple+message
```

In this case, you are replacing `message` on every iteration with the value of `message` and `subject` and `sender`. So, you are nesting the `message` tuple.

To fix that, try using some other variable name

```
message1 = (subject, message, sender)
rec_tuple = rec_tuple + message1
```

Better use the tuple as it is

```
rec_tuple = rec_tuple + (subject, message, sender)
```

Even better, use short hand notation

```
rec_tuple += (subject, message, sender)
```

This lets the user understand that you are concatenating the tuples and reduces the number of lines as well.

**Output**

```
('c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're stomping on `message` in the loop. Use a different name.

Comment: I feel so dumb. I've been staring at this thing for like 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the variable "message" for two different purposes. Fix that and your problem will go away.